# счётчик символов с возможностью копирования результата script html

Tags: html

Это просто счётчик символов с возможностью копирования результата
То есть вы пишите в текстовое поле слова. Жмете заправить - скрипт считает записывает в `div` - жмёте `COPY...`, но процедура копирования результата - число символов не происходит. ПОЧЕМУ???

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("Copy");

  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("OK")
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="35" id="text" rows="8"></textarea>
<div><button class="buttonCOPI" id="visible-button" onclick="send()">ЗАПРАВИТЬ</button></div>
<div class="DIVsimvol">СИМВОЛОВ:
  <div>
    <div class="SimvolClass" id="simvol">0</div>
  </div>
  <div><button onclick="CopyToClipboard('simvol')">COPY</button></div>
</div>
<script>
  function send() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    document.getElementById("simvol").innerHTML = text.length;
  }
</script>
```

Я уже замучился...) Несколько часов ищу) Наверняка что-то элементарное...

Comment: А вы сами проверяли? У меня копирует.

Comment: Странно) У меня вставляется то что сейчас в буфере а не результат работы скрипта. У меня хром, в опере тоже не работает

Comment: @polygon что должно копироваться - число символов или текст из textarea?

Comment: должно копироваться чисто символов! спасибо, исправил. @UModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу в учебник надо было глянуть) [Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection#%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  var target = document.getElementById(containerid);
  var rng, sel;
  if (document.createRange) {
    rng = document.createRange();
    rng.selectNode(target)
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(rng);
  } else {
    var rng = document.body.createTextRange();
    rng.moveToElementText(target);
    rng.select();
  }
  document.execCommand('Copy');
  sel.removeAllRanges();
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="35" id="text" rows="8"></textarea>
<div>
  <button class="buttonCOPI" id="visible-button" onclick="send()">ЗАПРАВИТЬ</button>
</div>

<div class="DIVsimvol">СИМВОЛОВ:
  <div>
    <div class="SimvolClass" id="simvol">0</div>
  </div>

  <div><button onclick="CopyToClipboard('simvol')">COPY</button></div>
</div>

<script>
  function send() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    document.getElementById('simvol').innerHTML = text.length;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за учебник! и ответ! всё работает.